# Crop three.js canvas in react without scaling

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I am very new to webdev and have probably a very simple question.

I have a three.js scene as a component in a react page.  Currently the canvas fills the screen:
`renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth  , window.innerHeight );`

I want the canvas to maintain its screen width, but crop vertically, like more of a banner shape.  The problem I find is that if I adjust the setSize parameters, any changes cause the scene to stretch/squeeze rather than crop.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a bit of a hack so I would still like to hear any opinions on this, but I have solved it by squeezing the camera, and then unsqueezing the canvas, for example:

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth / (window.innerHeight / 1.6) , 0.1, 1000);

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth  , window.innerHeight / 1.6 );
```